# Hotplug scripts not working xen

Tags: virtualization, xen, centos6

I am using CentOS 6.5 64

using this script to install xen on server

```
yum install http://fedora.cu.be/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install centos-release-xen
yum install xen
/usr/bin/grub-bootxen.sh
reboot
```

**Bridging**

`[root@CentOS ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.08002754b3fa       no              eth0`

I tried to create new virtual machine using xm command

**Xen configuration file**

`kernel = "/var/lib/xen/images/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/var/lib/xen/images/initrd.img"
extra = "text ks=http://192.168.1.8/kickstart-minimal6-x86_64.cfg"
name = "xc63"
memory = "512"
disk = [ "file:/var/lib/xen/images/centos63.img,xvda,w","file:/var/lib/xen/images/centos63.swp,xvdb,w" ]
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]
vcpus = 1
on_reboot = "destroy"
on_crash = "destroy"`

when start creating I am getting this error

`[root@CentOS images]# xm create xen_1
Using config file "./xen_1".
Error: Device 0 (vif) could not be connected. Hotplug scripts not working`

I get this error in `/var/log/xen/xen-hotplug.log`

`/etc/xen/scripts/locking.sh: line 60: perl: command not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install `perl` to get it working.  Try

```
# yum install perl
```

You can test whether it's working by issueing:

```
$ perl -e 'print("Hello, world!\n");'
Hello, world!
```

If it still does not work, check the script that issues the error and look whether it eventually resets the `PATH` variable.  It's also possible that the start script starts Xen without the directory containing `perl` in `$PATH`.  You could prevent this by finding out where your `perl` binary is located:

```
$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

and adding a line like

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin"
```

at the beginning of the `locking.sh` script.

Also note that since Xen version 4.3 the `xm` tool (like `xend`) is deprecated in favor of `xl`.

Comment: I installed but not working and the same error :(

Comment: the `perl` working

Comment: the line cause the problem :
       `rightfile=$( perl -e '
open STDIN, "<&'$_lockfd'" or die $!;
my $fd_inum = (stat STDIN)[1]; die $! unless defined $fd_inum;
my $file_inum = (stat $ARGV[0])[1];
print "y\n" if $fd_inum eq $file_inum;
' "$_lockfile" )`

Comment: Please see the update of my post, especially the last part about the `$PATH`.

Comment: thank u, but not working :(

Comment: Define »not working«.

Comment: get same error.

Comment: build new server and install perl and its worked :D

Comment: Why do some guys never read an error-message?